# Проблема с вводом символов '+' и '-' через scanf на C

Tags: c, ввод, scanf

Доброго времени суток всем. При написании кода возникла следующая проблема: при попытке ввести число, когда на вход подается символ, программа уже не могла считать повторно символы + или - . Вот код:

```
int main() {
    int a ;
    char c;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%c", &c);
    printf("%d", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Любые символы, кроме указанных двух вводятся и выводятся корректно, а при + или - получаю "10", т.е. считывается почему-то пробел.

Как можно решить данную проблему? Заранее спасибо всем, кто откликнется.

Comment: Потому что `+` и `-` являются корректными первыми символами чисел.

Comment: и как тогда я могу считать эти символы? Мне нужен именно их код

Comment: Считывайте строку и разбирайте ее. Как вы, грубо говоря, глазами отличаете, что введено? вот так и объясните компьютеру. Можно попытаться брать очередной символ и смотреть, не цифра ли это. Если цифра - `ungetc` и чтение числа... но что-то мне непонятно - а как вы тогда собираетесь вводить отрицательные числа, например?...

Comment: `Любые символы, кроме указанных двух`? Или вы с другими символами пробел не вводите? Пробел - вполне валидный символ для %c

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант- это указать в первом scanf() знак разделителя(whitespace). тогда , после ввода первого числа, введенный вами пробел(или пробелы, табуляция(ии), перенос(ы) строки) будет(ут) пропущен(ы). И следующий непустой символ попадет в 'c'

```
    int main() {
        int a ;
        char c;
        scanf("%d ", &a);
        //       ^ тут добавляем пробел
        scanf("%c", &c);
        printf("%d", c);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто объедините инструкции:

```
int main() {
    int a ;
    char c;
    scanf("%d %c", &a, &c); // >> 10  +
    printf("%d", c);        // << 43
    return 0;
}
```